# Replacement lens-board ring name and sourcing

Tags: lens, film, old-lenses, large-format

I've been having a hard time buying a good large format lens from eBay. I'm on my third order and the lens looks great, but it's missing the small ring that tightens the lens to the lens board. I'd rather not return a third lens (we're going on greater than two months here), but buy this small part to make it work.

What is that part called, and where could I buy it?

This is a Rodenstock Sironar-N 210mm, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring should be matched to the lens board and shutter, not the lens. You need to find a ring that matches whatever lensboard you plan to use. Of course your lens also needs to be made to fit the shutter/lens board you plan to use.

A simple google search for something like "lens board ring Copal #0" should give you all kinds of links to eBay sellers with the appropriate ring you need.

Comment: Thanks! And do I need to worry about the thread specs (angle, count), or is that pretty standard?

Comment: It *should* be the same for all rings made to fit a specific shutter/lens board. It could vary when made for a different shutter/lens board. Diameter is the most obvious difference from one shutter to the next.

Comment: For Rodenstock lenses current as of 2000, you can see the specs [here](http://www.prograf.ru/rodenstock/largeformat_en.html#image%20circles). Notice that the same lenses are offered for a wide variety of shutters.